# How can I use view > tile mode for only one chunk of a tilesheet in Aesprite?

Tags: sprite, image-sprite

Aesprite has a "View > Tilemode" option.  It will repeat the image so that you can make seamless tiles.

Unfortunately, I can only make it repeat entire images.  This is not very helpful because the tiles that I'm trying to make seamless are part of the tile sheets.

How do I make it repeat only the tile I want to work on, and not the whole tile sheet?